# calculadora python wxpython error logico

Tags: python, lógica, aplicación-escritorio, calculo, wxpython

estoy buscando ayuda con la lógica de mi código.
El proyecto es una calculadora sencilla en wxpython, ya le bindie los botones y le asigne funciones del teclado a los botones sin mucho inconveniente.
Mi problema surge en las operaciones matemáticas, en Onsum() todo sale perfecto, incluso puedo hacer sumas consecutivas sin la necesidad de presionar el signo igual.
En Onrest() sale bien la operacion si hago unicamente dos numeros, pero al intentar hacer operaciones consecutivas como lo hago con Onsum me arroja cualquier resultado.
Aun me faltan funciones que terminar como indicarle que al haber esperando un operador y presionar el otro cambie de operacion, pero me siento estancado en la parte de la logica de Onrest().
Agradezco la ayuda. subo el codigo:

```
import wx

class Calculadora(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        
        
        self.Title = "Calcularte"
        mainsz=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pantalla = self.pantalla()
        panel = self.caja()
        
        mainsz.Add(pantalla, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainsz.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainsz)
        self.Layout
        self.boton1.SetFocus()
        
        
    def pantalla(self):
        self.pantalla = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RIGHT, value= '0')
        fuente= wx.Font(20, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE , wx.FONTSTYLE_MAX, wx.FONTWEIGHT_EXTRABOLD)
        self.pantalla.SetFont(fuente)
        self.val =  0
        self.numeros = ""
        self.op_pendiente = None
        return self.pantalla
        
        
        
        
    def caja(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Center()
        
        
        #----------------------Botones----------------------#
        bot_tamaño = (40, 40)
        igual_tamaño = (84, 40)
        
        self.boton1 = wx.Button(panel, label= '1', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton2 = wx.Button(panel, label= '2',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton3 = wx.Button(panel, label= '3',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        
        self.boton4 = wx.Button(panel, label= '4',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton5 = wx.Button(panel, label= '5',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton6 = wx.Button(panel, label= '6',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        
        self.boton7 = wx.Button(panel, label= '7',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton8 = wx.Button(panel, label= '8',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton9 = wx.Button(panel, label= '9',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        
        self.botonC = wx.Button(panel, label= 'C', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.botonDel = wx.Button(panel, label= 'Del', size=igual_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.boton0 = wx.Button(panel, label= '0', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.botoncoma = wx.Button(panel, label= '.', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        
        self.botonsum = wx.Button(panel, label= '+',size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.botonmult = wx.Button(panel, label= '*', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.botonrest = wx.Button(panel, label= '-', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.botondiv = wx.Button(panel, label= '/', size=bot_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.botonigual = wx.Button(panel, label= '=', size=igual_tamaño, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        
        #----------------Grid----------------#
        teclado = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=4, hgap=4) 
        
        teclado.Add(self.boton1,(0,0))
        teclado.Add(self.boton2,(0,1))
        teclado.Add(self.boton3,(0,2))
        
        teclado.Add(self.boton4,(1,0))
        teclado.Add(self.boton5,(1,1))
        teclado.Add(self.boton6,(1,2))
        
        teclado.Add(self.boton7,(2,0))
        teclado.Add(self.boton8,(2,1))
        teclado.Add(self.boton9,(2,2))
        
        teclado.Add(self.botonDel,(2,3), span =(1,2))
        teclado.Add(self.botonC,(3,0))
        teclado.Add(self.boton0,(3,1))
        teclado.Add(self.botoncoma,(3,2))
        
        teclado.Add(self.botonsum,pos=(0,3))
        teclado.Add(self.botonrest,pos=(1,3))
        teclado.Add(self.botonmult,pos=(0,4))
        teclado.Add(self.botondiv,pos=(1,4))
        teclado.Add(self.botonigual, pos=(3,3),span=(1,2))
        
    #------------Bind------------#
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On0, self.boton0)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On1, self.boton1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On2, self.boton2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On3, self.boton3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On4, self.boton4)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On5, self.boton5)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On6, self.boton6)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On7, self.boton7)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On8, self.boton8)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On9, self.boton9)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Oncoma, self.botoncoma)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnC, self.botonC)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onsum, self.botonsum)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onrest, self.botonrest)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onmult, self.botonmult)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Ondiv, self.botondiv)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onigual, self.botonigual)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDelete, self.botonDel)
    #---------Bindear botones con el teclado---------#
        self.boton1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnKey)
       
        
        panel.SetSizer(teclado)
        return panel
        
    #--------------Funciones de botones--------------#   
    def On0(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('0')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'0')
            
    def On1(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('1')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'1')
            
    def On2(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('2')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'2')
            
    def On3(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('3')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'3')
            
    def On4(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('4')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'4')
            
    def On5(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('5')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'5')
            
    def On6(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('6')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'6')
            
    def On7(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('7')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'7')
            
    def On8(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('8')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'8')
            
    def On9(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            self.pantalla.SetValue('9')
        else: 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+'9')
            
    def Oncoma(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla.find(".")==-1:
            self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla+".")
        else :
            pass
        
    def OnC(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.SetValue('0')
        self.val = 0.0
        
    def Onsum(self, e):
        val_pantalla = float(self.pantalla.GetValue()) 
        self.op_pendiente = "suma"
        if self.op_pendiente == "suma":
            self.val = val_pantalla + self.val 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(str(self.val))
            self.pantalla.SetValue('0')
            self.op_pendiente = "suma"
            
            
    def Onrest(self, e):
        val_pantalla = float(self.pantalla.GetValue()) 
        self.op_pendiente = "resta"
        if self.op_pendiente == "resta":
            self.val = val_pantalla - self.val 
            self.pantalla.SetValue(str(self.val))
            self.pantalla.SetValue('')
            self.op_pendiente = "resta"

        

        
    def Onmult(self, e):
        val_pantalla = float(self.pantalla.GetValue())
        self.pantalla.SetValue('0')
        if self.op_pendiente == 'multi':
            self.val *= val_pantalla
        else:
            self.val = val_pantalla
        self.op_pendiente = 'multi'
        
    def Ondiv(self, e):
        val_pantalla = float(self.pantalla.GetValue())
        self.pantalla.SetValue('0')
        if self.op_pendiente == 'divi':
            if val_pantalla != '0':
                self.val /= val_pantalla
            else:
                self.pantalla.SetValue('Error al dividir 0')
                return
        else: 
            self.val = val_pantalla
        self.op_pendiente = 'divi'
        
    def Onigual(self, e):
        val_pantalla = float(self.pantalla.GetValue())
        if self.op_pendiente == "suma":
            self.val += val_pantalla
        elif self.op_pendiente == "resta":
            self.val -= val_pantalla
        elif self.op_pendiente == "multi":
            self.val *= val_pantalla
        elif self.op_pendiente == "divi":
            self.val /= val_pantalla
    
        self.op_pendiente = None
        self.numeros = []
        self.pantalla.SetValue(str(self.val))
        
    def OnDelete(self, e):
        val_pantalla = self.pantalla.GetValue()
        if val_pantalla == '0':
            pass
        else: 
            if len(val_pantalla)== 1:
                self.pantalla.SetValue('0')
            else:
                self.pantalla.SetValue(val_pantalla[:-1])
    
    def OnKey(self, e):
        key_code = e.GetKeyCode()
        print(f"Key code: {key_code}")
        if key_code == 49 or key_code ==325:
            self.On1(None)
        if key_code == 50 or key_code == 326:
            self.On2(None)
        if key_code == 51 or key_code == 327:
            self.On3(None)
        if key_code == 52 or key_code == 328:
            self.On4(None)    
        if key_code == 53 or key_code == 329:
            self.On5(None)
        if key_code == 54 or key_code == 330:
            self.On6(None)
        if key_code == 55 or key_code == 331:
            self.On7(None)
        if key_code == 56 or key_code == 332:
            self.On8(None)
        if key_code == 57 or key_code == 333:
            self.On9(None)
        if key_code == 58 or key_code == 324:
            self.On0(None)
        if key_code == 67 or key_code == 127 or key_code == 27:
            self.OnC(None)
        if key_code == 46 or key_code == 391:
            self.Oncoma(None)
        if key_code == 43 or key_code == 388:
            self.Onsum(None)
        if key_code == 45 or key_code == 390:
            self.Onrest(None)
        if key_code == 387:
            self.Onmult(None)
        if key_code == 392:
            self.Ondiv(None)  
        if key_code == 13 or key_code == 370:
            self.Onigual(None)
        if key_code == 8:
            self.OnDelete(None)
        
        
        e.Skip()            
        
        
     
        
              
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    interfaz = Calculadora(None, size =(233,251), style=wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX)
    interfaz.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sacando lo que pase con resta, haces una cosa que no tiene sentido: `self.op_pendiente = 'X'` -> `if self.op_pendiente = 'X'`-> `self.op_pendiente = `X`. Primero, el if sobra completamente... si haces que el valor sea X no necesitas comprobar en la siguiente línea si es X, obviamente va a ser X, no puede ser otra cosa porque acabas de asignarlo a eso tu mismo! Y luego al terminar vuelves a asignarle el mismo valor que ya tiene, lo cual también es innecesario. En cuanto a tu problema... creo que viene porque no estás parseando el valor que obtienes de pantalla, que es un string!

Comment: El tema de """self.op_pendiente = 'x' """ fue lo que se me ocurrió para realizar operaciones constantes, quizás debería haberlo hecho con un while?.

Comment: El método se invoca cada vez que pulsas en la tecla... no necesitas un while. Pero tampoco necesitas asignarlo y en la línea siguiente comprobar que vale eso. Claro que vale eso, lo acabas de asignar en la línea anterior!! Nunca va a valer otra cosa.

Comment: claro entiendo. al final desisti de esa manera de hacerlo y opte por cambiar todo el codigo de ecuaciones. opte por sacar el op_pendiente